# Python : Getting values of key from JSON

Tags: python, json

Wrote a python script to collect the response header of a list of websites.Now,I have json file which has the `response header` of website. `1` is the ID `(key)` and rest all `values` are the response header parsed for a particular URL.

```
 {
    "1": {
        "transfer-encoding": "chunked", 
        "set-cookie": "lng=hi; path=/; expires=Tue, 14-Feb-2017 08:54:15 GMT; domain=.ucoz.net;, uSID=HYv2D8GG3nmptnLPRZbxuxBHi5awMLA8pwrSRf2aE8t0l9%3BEeTKJkgoo; path=/; domain=www.ucoz.net;", 
        "keep-alive": "timeout=15", 
        "server": "nginx/1.8.0", 
        "connection": "keep-alive", 
        "date": "Mon, 15 Feb 2016 08:54:15 GMT", 
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    }
}
```

How to get the value of server for key `1`

Result :

```
1,nginx/1.8.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JSON encoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse data in your file:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('json_data.json') as json_data:    
    data = json.load(json_data)

pprint(data)
# now you can traverse your data dict....
print(data['1']['server'])
```

Answer (score 3):

`json.loads`: Deserialize `data` (instance containing a JSON) to a Python object.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = ''' {
...     "1": {
...         "transfer-encoding": "chunked", 
...         "set-cookie": "lng=hi; path=/; expires=Tue, 14-Feb-2017 08:54:15 GMT; domain=.ucoz.net;, uSID=HYv2D8GG3nmptnLPRZbxuxBHi5awMLA8pwrSRf2aE8t0l9%3BEeTKJkgoo; path=/; domain=www.ucoz.net;", 
...         "keep-alive": "timeout=15", 
...         "server": "nginx/1.8.0", 
...         "connection": "keep-alive", 
...         "date": "Mon, 15 Feb 2016 08:54:15 GMT", 
...         "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
...     }
... }'''
>>> d = json.loads(data)
>>> d['1']['server']
u'nginx/1.8.0'
```